# The generation of the Borel set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I saw two different way to generate the Borel Set.

Denote by $B$ the $\sigma-$ring generated by the class of all open sets of $X$.The sets of $B$ are Borel sets.

Denote by $B$ the $\sigma-$algebra generated by the class of all open subsets of $X$.The sets of $B$ are Borel sets.

I have a question: could I replace the "open sets" by "open subsets"?

"Denote by $B$ the $\sigma-$ring generated by the class of all open subsets of $X$.The sets of $B$ are Borel sets."

Because I think the whole set $X \subseteq X$, $X$ is a subset of $X$ too. And $\sigma-$ring + $X \in B$ = $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: Sounds right to me -- an "open set of X" must be a (possibly improper) subset.

Comment: Yes, with "**an** open set" indeed instead of "**the** open set".